# Can you go backwards in a block chain?

Tags: blockchain

Can you go backwards in a block chain to unhash an old ledger and see the transaction details?

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of how blockchains work. There is no hashing and hiding of transactions. Transactions are identified by their hashes and the hash is stored in a block, along with the transaction. There is no need for "unhashing" to see transaction details, the details are all there.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that each block/ledger was hashed after a certain number of transactions, and that hash then became line1 of the next block. So, is the entire chain of blocks pushed along from genesis to today?

Comment: Yes, the entire blockchain (which is the collection of all blocks) is publicly available and stored by full nodes. Furthermore, all blocks are verified by all full nodes.